# Trim a small empty triangle on top of a div

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a drop down menu, without any images, Pure CSS and HTML like the following:
[image]

What I'm not able to do is make this little Triangle shaped trim on Top

is it possible in CSS, if it is, how?

Comment: Use an image for the same?

Comment: I don't want to Use Images if it can be done without using images.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Live Example: http://jsbin.com/owafod/1/

I used [CSS triangle generator](http://apps.eky.hk/css-triangle-generator/) to create the triangle.

```
#Nav { 
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #333;
}

#Triangle {
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 10px 10px 0 10px;
    border-color: #ffffff transparent transparent transparent;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Wow. Thanks very much, still looking amazed to the code wondering how it's done.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution with borders :

Result :

[image]

HTML :

```
  <div id=a></div><div id=b></div>  
  <div id=c></div>
```

CSS :

```
#a {
  border-right: 5px solid white;
  border-bottom: 5px solid black;
  width: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin:0;
}
#b {
  border-left: 5px solid white;
  border-bottom: 5px solid black;
  width: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin:0;
}
#c {
   background: black; height:20px;width:210px
}
```

**[Tests](http://jsbin.com/awemet/1/edit)**

---

And here's a picture that will probably suffice to explain how it's made and how you can easily use this kind of border trick :

[image]

([the code to make it](http://jsbin.com/awemet/2/edit))